# Dropbox gives an error message when starting up but then it disappears

Tags: dropbox

Something like "cannot monitor file system , run sudo tee 1000 |"..., but then it disappears before I can read the full message.
Dropbox seems to work ok so not sure what this is about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dropbox has a help center and a user forum: [Help](https://www.dropbox.com/help) and [Forum](http://forums.dropbox.com/).  Is [this thread](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=29130&replies=18#post-183199) related to your problem?

Comment: Yes that fixed it, thx.